# org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request binance

Tags: java, resttemplate

I'm trying to post order to the binance by using RestTemplate. The next simplified code:

```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("user-agent",
            "Mozilla/5.0 " +
                    "(Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) " +
                    "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) " +
                    "Chrome/54.0.2840.99 " +
                    "Safari/537.36");
    headers.add(X_MBX_APIKEY, apiKey);

    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>("parameters", headers);

    long time = new Date().getTime();
    String params1 = "symbol=LTCBTC&side=BUY&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC&quantity=1&price=0.005&recvWindow=50000" +
            "&timestamp=" + time;
    String signature = encodeSHA256(secretKey, params1);
    UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("https://api.binance.com/api/v3/order/test")
            .queryParam("symbol", "LTCBTC")
            .queryParam("side", "BUY")
            .queryParam("type", "LIMIT")
            .queryParam("timeInForce", "GTC")
            .queryParam("quantity", "1")
            .queryParam("price", "0.005")
            .queryParam("recvWindow", "50000")
            .queryParam("timestamp", time)
            .queryParam("signature", signature);
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(builder.build().toUri(), HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
```

So I get next exception:

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request: [{"code":-1104,"msg":"Not all sent parameters were read; read '9' parameter(s) but was sent '10'."}]
at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:101)
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:170)
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:112)
at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:782)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:740)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:714)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:602)
```

The same request in postman works well. So what is the reason of this error? Because the quantity of parameters is 9 in request. Maybe binance api recognize the apiKey in header as 10-th parameter? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think this question to the API owner.

Answer (score 0):

I don't no why restTemplate is not working, but I copied the code from postman that is using okhttp3. And now it works.

```
        long time = new Date().getTime();
        String params = "symbol=LTCBTC&side=BUY&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC&quantity=1" +
        "&price=0.004&recvWindow=50000" +
                "&timestamp=" + time;
        String signature = encodeSHA256(marketKey, params);
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://api.binance.com/api/v3/order" +
                        "?symbol=LTCBTC&side=BUY&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC&quantity=1" +
                        "&price=0.004&recvWindow=50000" +
                        "&timestamp=" + time +
                        "&signature=" + signature)
                .post(new RequestBody() {
                    @Nullable
                    @Override
                    public MediaType contentType() {
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void writeTo(BufferedSink bufferedSink) throws IOException {

                    }
                })
                .addHeader("X-MBX-APIKEY", apiKey)
                .build();
```